# Replace multiple hosts of gke ingress using kustomize overlays

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, overlay, kubernetes-ingress, kustomize

I have a GKE/GCE ingress file which has 2 hosts.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myfirstdomain # <-------- override this via kustomize
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /abc
        backend:
          serviceName: abc
          servicePort: abc
      - path: /def
        backend:
          serviceName: def
          servicePort: def
      - path: /ghi
        backend:
          serviceName: ghi
          servicePort: ghi
  - host: myseconddomain # <-------- override this via kustomize
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: xyz
          servicePort: xyz
```

I want to declare the `host` values via kustomize so that i can specify different `host` values for different environments.

My overlay patch file for dev environment looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev1.example.com
  - host: dev2.example.com
```

However, the output of running `kustomize build overlays/dev` looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev1.example.com
  - host: dev2.example.com
```

---

## All other specs are lost.

It ends up replacing the **entire** `host` blocks instead of replacing just the `host` lines.

How can i solve this? I am using:

- **kustomize** version `v4.1.2`
- **kubectl** version `v1.21.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not do that using **[strategic merge](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patchesstrategicmerge/)** since the `spec.rules` is an array of items. You have to use **[json merge](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patchesjson6902/)** by providing the exact paths to be impacted.

You can create a separate patch file for json merge like below:

```yaml
# overlays/dev/ingress-json-patch.yaml

- op: replace
  path: /spec/rules/0/host
  value: dev1.example.com
- op: replace
  path: /spec/rules/1/host
  value: dev2.example.com
```

Then refer to that patch file by adding the following into your `kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
# overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml

patchesJson6902:
- target:
    group: extensions
    version: v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    name: my-ingress
  path: overlays/dev/ingress-json-patch.yaml
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could I ask why you have `group:extensions`? This only worked for me omitting `group: extensions`.